# Rails 4 not detecting my ruby 2.0.0 installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-on-rails-4

When I check `rails -v` I get

```
Rails 4 prefers to run on Ruby 2.0.

You're running
  ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

Please upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 or newer to continue.
```

However, I already have 2.0.0 installed. When I run `ruby -v`I get: 
`ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]`

What should I do?

Comment: are you using ruby with a version manager like RVM ?

Comment: yes, `rvm -v'rvm 1.22.3 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is most likely not using an rvm ruby, try running:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
gem install rails
```